# How can I embed a 3D image in a presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, google-drive, presentations, 3d, libreoffice-impress

I would like to embed a 3D object in a slide presentation, so that I can rotate it during a presentation.

I have a .obj file.

Is this possible?

I generally use PowerPoint, but am open to using Google Docs or OpenOffice. I am not quite ready to switch to Latex / Markdown / html for presentations (though I do use these for writing).

Comment: I have never done this so I'm just guessing here. I'd assume that getting PowerPoint to handle hardware rendering is going to be virtually impossible. You may be able to get a flash animation to fake what you want pretty good though. If you can make the flash animation acceptable for your requirements then you can follow these instruction to embed within PowerPoint: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/play-a-macromedia-flash-animation-in-powerpoint-HA001034807.aspx